# Add additional fee to product based on attribute set or category

Tags: catalog, price-rules

I would like to add additional cost to basic product cost based on attribute set or category or additional field can be added upon adding a new product product.

There are two requirements:

1. A fixed price can be added to product.
2. By percentage

I have looked at Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules, which is handy option to offer discounts on products based on attribute set or category price.

Is it possible to achieve something similar but instead of discount, it will add fixed cost or by percentage to the catalog price?

This is kind of service cost based on product variation. It will vary from product groups. I do not want to show such cost separately on shopping cart. So this will be calculated and added to catalog price.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible by default with Magento as you cannot use a negative value in the Shopping cart rule. Searching for an extension to add extra charges to an order gives lots of extensions, not sure if all of them can handle an extra charge based on the product.

The Surcharge extension from Fooman (Paid extension) can handle this (based on the description from the website), here you can specify different additional fees according to a range of flexible criteria including payment method, customer type, product, country or region of order, and even shipping method.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I checked with Surcharge extension from Fooman, they don't provide such functionality.
However, I found my solution from http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-percentage-pricing.html

Comment: Interesting approach.  Never have had a need for such a thing.  But cool!

Answer (score 2):

I have developed module with such functionality. It allows to add extra fee based on Shopping Cart Price Rules, and doesn't break discount functionality.
Module add new total collectors and it handles extra fee to totals.

GitHub Link: https://github.com/yvoronoy/magento-extension-extra-fee

[image: Extra Fee Based on Shopping Cart Price Rule]

Comment: not worked Magento ver. 1.9.0.1